# TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed- when creating dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary of dataframes imported from *yahoo*.

This doesn't work:

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web
symbols = ['BTC-EUR','ETH-EUR' ]
dict_of_stock = { web.DataReader(s, "yahoo") for s in (symbols) }
```

Out:

```py
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __hash__(self)
  1797     def __hash__(self):
  1798         raise TypeError(
-> 1799             f"{repr(type(self).__name__)} objects are mutable, "
  1800             f"thus they cannot be hashed"
  1801         )

TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

However this does:

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web
symbols = ['BTC-EUR','ETH-EUR' ]

dict_of_stock = {}

for s in symbols:
   #do some calcs to get a dataframe called 'df'
   dict_of_stock[s] = web.DataReader(s, "yahoo")
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
dict_of_stock = { web.DataReader(s, "yahoo") for s in (symbols) }
```

To:

```
dict_of_stock = { s: web.DataReader(s, "yahoo") for s in (symbols) }
```

In your earlier approach, the key to the dictionary was missing and hence the DataFrame was assumed as the key. That resulted in the error.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer for future generations?

Comment: I was writing the same answer but yours got published first. LoL

Comment: @Roy2012, have to wait 10 min!